# undefined reference when accessing static constexpr float member

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr, one-definition-rule

This code works:

```
struct Blob {
    static constexpr int a = 10;
};

int main() {
    Blob b;
    auto c = b.a;
}
```

But if I change `int` to `float` I get an error:

```
struct Blob {
    static constexpr float a = 10.0f;
};
```

> /tmp/main-272d80.o: In function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0xe):
>   undefined reference to`Blob::a'

Why can't I use a `constexpr float` in that way?

Compiler:
Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final)

Tested on gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) and there were no error.

**EDIT:**

It will compile if I use -O1, -O2, -O3 or -Os but fails with -O0

Comment: Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final)

Comment: @Deduplicator `error: non-static data member cannot be constexpr; did you intend to make it static?`

Comment: It compiles with clang 3.5.0 here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4c63c92dfcc9b3d

Comment: Can't [reproduce](http://rextester.com/CASWM32415) on clang 3.4

Comment: It compiles on my gcc too, some bug in clang?

Comment: Definitely compiles in clang++ 3.7.0 from last weekend.

Comment: @interjay It works for me too using -O3 :)

Comment: Reproduced when compiling on clang 3.5.0 without optimizations: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/357f3c94d573b048

Comment: I want to say that this is invalid C++11 and valid C++14 but don't have my references on me at the moment.

Comment: *N3690: A static data member of literal type can be declared in the
class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. ...  **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope** if it is odr-used n the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer..* -- I don't know where it actually says the `int`version is allowed

Comment: It seems to be working by accident when compiling the OP example, because despite turning on optimization in my project, I still get the same error.

Comment: @RyanHaining The question is whether it is odr-used or not.

Comment: Filed a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22565) and it was resolved as a duplicate of [this one](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18781) which is similar, which confirms it is indeed a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 reads

> A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is
>   *odr-used* **unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for
>   appearing in a constant expression (5.19)** and the lvalue-to-rvalue
>   conversion (4.1) is immediately applied.

Clearly the l-t-r conversion is immediately applied, and a `constexpr` variable of floating point type can appear in constant expressions as per [expr.const]/(2.7.1):

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>   [..]
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
>   - **a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`**, or that refers to a sub-object of such an
>       object, or

Seems to be a Clang bug.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, if we use `Blob::a` instead, `clang` does not complain:

```
auto c = Blob::a;
```

This should not matter for determining if the it is odr-used or not. So this looks like a `clang` bug which I can reproduce on [clang 3.7](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HZVocw6OXd5GmK0K) using no optimization only. We can tell this is an odr issue since adding a out of class definition fixes the issue (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vm8eSE493RsNQUXm)*):

```
constexpr float Blob::a ;
```

So when do you need to define a static constexpr class member? This is covered in section `9.4.2` *[class.static.data]* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> A static data member of literal type can be declared in the
>   class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer
>   in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end note ] **The member shall still be defined
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2)** in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
>   contain an initializer.

It requires a definition if it is odr-used. Is it odr-used? No, it is not. The original C++11 wording in section `3.2` *[basic.def.odr]* says:

> An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression
>   thereof. A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression **is odr-used unless** it is an
>   object that **satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression** (5.19) and **the lvalue-to-rvalue
>   conversion (4.1) is immediately applied**.

`a` satisfies both conditions, it is a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied. [Defect Report 712](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#712) has changed the wording which applies to C++11 since it is a defect report and `3.2` now says:

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex **is odr-used unless** applying the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to x yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke any non-trivial
>   functions and, if x is an object, ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e, where
>   either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a discarded-value expression

The potential result that matches would be:

> If e is an id-expression (5.1.1), the set contains only e.

it is a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied so it is not odr-used.